# WPF. Prevent MainWindow from cropping controls it contains because of resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

For example I have this simple markup in my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" Width="300" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Width="300" />
</Grid>
```

When I start the application and resize the main window I can make it smaller then the buttons' sizes as it crops the buttons.

I have tried setting the MinWidth properties - that didn't work. The only way is to set the MinWidth of the whole window but it's not very maintainable solution.

**UPDATE**
Evetually I have found a solution.
I added event handler for MainWindow SizeChanged. with following code:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement topmost = (Content as FrameworkElement);
    topmost.Measure(new Size(ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
    MinHeight = topmost.DesiredSize.Height + 40;
    MinWidth = topmost.DesiredSize.Width;
}
```

I found out that the Measure method of any FrameWorkelement forces it to calculate space it wants to occupy with the given amount of space it CAN occupy and considering all its child elements and stores it to the DesiredSize property. So I call the Measure method of the window's topmost element with the current size of the window and in the DesiredSize I get the minimum size of everything in the window. Then I set the MinHeight and the MinWidth of the window to this minimum size values. And it does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

While @Dimitry M's solution works, there's a simpler solution without magic values. Set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and bind an event listener to Window's `ContentRendered` event:

```xml
<Window ...
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        ContentRendered="MainWindow_OnContentRendered">
```

This will force the window to fit its contents, Then once it's rendered, we prevent resizing down by setting its minimum size to actual size.

```cs
private void MainWindow_OnContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MinWidth = ActualWidth;
    MinHeight = ActualHeight;
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty clean solution even for MVVM. Out of curiosity, is there any way to do this with Binding rather than code-behind? If I bind the Window's MinWidth to my View's ActualWidth it still cuts the view off slightly. Binding to the Window's ActualWidth doesn't work at all.

Comment: Some components might be changing in size after `ContentRendered` event is fired. I'm not well versed in WPF, but if the component (that gets cut off) fires an event after its dimensions change, maybe you could listen to that (assuming the event bubbles up) and set the minimum size accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Buttons' `Height`.

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" />
```

this will cause the buttons to resize according to the Window Size.

Comment: Yes, but it is a general example. If I want the controls inside the window to be exactly the size I specified and want the window not to crop them when being resized.

Comment: @dmitrymarchuk that is physically impossible. I don't understand what you're saying. If Button Width = 50 and Window Width = 30, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: While resizing window from X to 30 I want it to stop at 50 and not to cut the button.

Comment: Add MinWidth \ MinHight to the grid and buttons